# winapi: GetUpdateRect() with bRepaint TRUE inside WM_PAINT doesn't clear the paint region, but InvalidateRect() outside WM_PAINT does?

Tags: winapi, go, gdi

My custom drawing area's WM_PAINT looks something like this:

```
// TRUE to clear the background
if (GetUpdateRect(hwnd, &r, TRUE) == 0)
    return; // no update rect; do nothing
dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
// check return
// paint some RGBA image data with GDI+
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

(Disregard the sending a HDC to GDI+ for now.)

I use `GetUpdateRect()` here instead of getting the update rect from `BeginPaint()` because I always want to draw over a blank canvas, especially since I'm doing alpha-mixed drawing here. Furthermore, [the docs for `WM_PAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say not to call `BeginPaint()` if `GetUpdateRect()` fails.

However, when my custom drawing area actually does this WM_PAINT, it isn't clearing the drawing area. I can tell because the alpha-enabled image is drawn on top of itself, resulting in darker colors.

In another part of my code, I respond to a keyboard event by calling `InvalidateRect()` to force an update of the whole area. If I change the equivalent of

```
InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
```

to

```
InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
```

the area does get cleared properly.

So what exactly AM I doing wrong here? Thanks.

(The actual code is [this](https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/master/area_windows.go); it's written in Go. This is also why I am working with GDI+ directly. (I have yet to figure out how to do alpha-mixed stuff with regular GDI.))

Comment: A huge chunk of code written in a language you didn't even tag interfacing with Win32 _and_ GDI+. My head hurts just thinking about the possibilities. I've added the Go tag, but you really need to boil your question down to something people can digest and even begin to help you with. If you can't state your question succinctly then you don't understand your own problem yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both of you. Stack Overflow will only let me award one check at a time though... And yep, after doing the clearing properly I got the flicker mentioned in the checked answer.

Ultimately I decided to throw out what I have so far, especially at the advice of Treeki/Ninjifox, who suggested I use the `AlphaBlend()` function instead. Now, though, I have more problems... but that'll be for another question, with a standalone example program.

Answer (score 3):

`InvalidateRect` invalidates the region, which means it is followed by erase/repaint requests. You compare it to `GetUpdateRect` which does not do validation or invalidation and with `TRUE` parameter erases the region the same way you would have it erased with standard painting. Furthermore [as MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144943):

> The update rectangle retrieved by the BeginPaint function is identical to that retrieved by GetUpdateRect.
>
> BeginPaint automatically validates the update region, so any call to GetUpdateRect made immediately after the call to BeginPaint retrieves an empty update region.

All together I don't see any reason to call `GetUpdateRect` the way you do it in paint handler. `BeginPaint` does it the same way, with validation, and you need to do it as soon as you are in paint handler anyway. Once you're there, erase handler is already called with no need to call it once again through `GetUpdateRect`.

`BeginPaint`'s `PAINTSTRUCT::rcPaint` gets you the update region the same way, just don't do anything before calling `EndPaint` if the update region is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> However, when my custom drawing area actually does this WM_PAINT, it isn't clearing the drawing area. I can tell because the alpha-enabled image is drawn on top of itself, resulting in darker colors.

There is nothing about WM_PAINT or the functions you call that will clear the region. If you want it cleared, you must do that yourself. Most programs don't, because clearing followed by painting causes flicker. If you don't clear and you do paint a transparent object, you have a problem. The solution may be to use off-screen drawing.

InvalidateRegion(,,true) is different. It sends WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_NCPAINT messages to the region is erased and painted.

There is no support for transparency in GDI. Some kinds of transparency can be simulated using masking operations.

Transparency support was introduced with GDI+, and is reasonably extensive although not much used. It's not hard to retrofit GDI+ effects into legacy code, including alpha-channel PNGs and the like.

The fancy effects from Vista depend on DirectX, which is a rather different drawing system. The Visual in WPF is very different from the old DC. You might want to consider writing new code using that system.